command `tk = tkinter.Tk()` in Python gives a `tkinter.TclError`: "This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly."
I am new to Python and trying to learn it. I am trying to create a window. The course I am following says to enter the following:
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

I get the follow error when I try to run it.
This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
I was going to try to install Tcl, but can't find an exe. I also believe that was installed during python installation.
I also tried uninstalling & reinstalling both Python and PyCharm with the same results
I am running Python 3.13.0 and PyCharm 2020.2.4 Community Edidtion.

What OS are you using?

have you checked this your question is more like a duplicate with less details uninstalling & reinstalling both Python and PyCharm : | atleast python, its okay to think it has problems, but how did you think pycharm is causing this??

Tcl isn't installed with Python. The reason some distributions omit tkinter (despite it being part of the standard library) is that Tcl/Tk is a rather large dependency outside the Python ecosystem, and it's basically dead weight if you don't use tkinter. Check the package manager of choice (apt, rpm, nix, etc) for options to install Tcl/Tk.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#default-interpreter

This question has been asked many times. Did you do any research before asking this question?

Hi have researched this and I wasn't sure of the steps to implement some of the suggestions. I am running Windows 11.

I dug out an old computer. Really slow and not much room, but it has Windows 10 and not Windows 11 like my main computer. I enter this code and it works....
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry("420x420")
window.title("Hello World")
window.mainloop()
Could this be a Windows 11 issue?

Being that this runs on an old windows 10 machine, I installed a virtual machine with Windows 10 on my main computer It doesn't work there either. So I can't create a window on this computer using Windows 10 or 11. I am at a loss.  My computer is high end with lots of speed, space, and processors. Not sure why it won't work here..

Does anyone know if this is an issue with Python or PyCharm. If you think it is PyCharm, can you recommend a different IDE that I could use?

It is a bug when using virtual environment with Python 3.13.0.

Sounds like there's half an installation behind there. I don't remember if 9.0 fixes this by binding files together by default; I know it can (I've tested that code) but that's subtly different from does.

What is 9.0? I have Python 3.13.0, PIP is 24.2, and PyCharm is 2024.2.4 Build #PC-242.23726.102. Is there an update I should have?
